# format a CSV file properly so as to fetch data from the CSV correctly

Tags: text-processing, csv-simple

I have a CSV file as below :

I want to remove the "`INITIAL OFFER`" block from this file and remain with only "`FINAL OFFER`" block
I also want to remove comma(,) from the first field and also remove extra spaces from the last column, so as to make search on these columns easier.

**INPUT**

```
500076592,      INITIAL OFFER
500076592,|11|1|1|100 MB|2 Minutes|1.0 SAR
500076592,|11|2|3|300 MB|5 Minutes|3.0 SAR
500076592,|1|1|1|100 MB|NA|0.5 SAR
500076592,|1|2|3|300 MB|NA|1.5 SAR
500076592,|1|4|7|1000 MB|NA|5.0 SAR
500076592,|2|1|1|4096 MB|NA|1.5 SAR
500076592,|2|2|3|6144 MB|NA|2.0 SAR
500076592,|2|4|7|10240 MB|NA|4.0 SAR
500076592,|5|1|1|4096 MB|NA|2.0 SAR
500076592,|5|2|3|6144 MB|NA|2.5 SAR
500076592,|5|4|7|10240 MB|NA|5.0 SAR
500076592,|6|1|1|NA|2 Minutes|0.5 SAR
500076592,|6|2|3|NA|5 Minutes|1.5 SAR
500076592,|6|4|7|NA|10 Minutes|3.0 SAR
500076592,
500076592,|FINAL OFFER
500076592,|2|1|1|4096 MB|NA|1.5 SAR
500076592,|2|2|3|6144 MB|NA|2.0 SAR
500076592,|2|4|7|10240 MB|NA|4.0 SAR
500076592,|5|1|1|4096 MB|NA|2.0 SAR
500076592,|5|2|3|6144 MB|NA|2.5 SAR
500076592,|5|4|7|10240 MB|NA|5.0 SAR
500076592,|1|1|1|100 MB|NA|0.5 SAR
500076592,|1|2|3|300 MB|NA|1.5 SAR
500076592,|1|4|7|1000 MB|NA|5.0 SAR
500076592,|11|1|1|100 MB|2 Minutes|1.0 SAR
500076592,|11|2|3|300 MB|5 Minutes|3.0 SAR
500076592,|6|1|1|NA|2 Minutes|0.5 SAR
500076592,|6|2|3|NA|5 Minutes|1.5 SAR
500076592,|6|4|7|NA|10 Minutes|3.0 SAR
500076592,
500028952,      INITIAL OFFER
500028952,|11|1|1|250 MB|2 Minutes|3.0 SAR
500028952,|11|2|3|650 MB|10 Minutes|8.0 SAR
500028952,|11|4|7|1550 MB|30 Minutes|18.5 SAR
500028952,|1|1|1|250 MB|NA|2.5 SAR
500028952,|1|2|3|650 MB|NA|6.5 SAR
500028952,|1|4|7|1550 MB|NA|15.5 SAR
500028952,|2|1|1|4096 MB|NA|1.5 SAR
500028952,|2|2|3|6144 MB|NA|2.0 SAR
500028952,|2|4|7|10240 MB|NA|4.0 SAR
500028952,|5|1|1|4096 MB|NA|2.0 SAR
500028952,|5|2|3|6144 MB|NA|2.5 SAR
500028952,|5|4|7|10240 MB|NA|5.0 SAR
500028952,|6|1|1|NA|2 Minutes|0.5 SAR
500028952,|6|2|3|NA|10 Minutes|1.5 SAR
500028952,|6|4|7|NA|30 Minutes|3.0 SAR
500028952,
500028952,|FINAL OFFER
500028952,|2|1|1|4096 MB|NA|1.5 SAR
500028952,|2|2|3|6144 MB|NA|2.0 SAR
500028952,|2|4|7|10240 MB|NA|4.0 SAR
500028952,|1|1|1|250 MB|NA|2.5 SAR
500028952,|1|2|3|650 MB|NA|6.5 SAR
500028952,|1|4|7|1550 MB|NA|15.5 SAR
500028952,|11|1|1|250 MB|2 Minutes|3.0 SAR
500028952,|11|2|3|650 MB|10 Minutes|8.0 SAR
500028952,|11|4|7|1550 MB|30 Minutes|18.5 SAR
500028952,|5|1|1|4096 MB|NA|2.0 SAR
500028952,|5|2|3|6144 MB|NA|2.5 SAR
500028952,|5|4|7|10240 MB|NA|5.0 SAR
500028952,|6|1|1|NA|2 Minutes|0.5 SAR
500028952,|6|2|3|NA|10 Minutes|1.5 SAR
500028952,|6|4|7|NA|30 Minutes|3.0 SAR
500028952,
```

**OUTPUT**

```
500076592,|FINAL OFFER
500076592,|2|1|1|4096 MB|NA|1.5 SAR
500076592,|2|2|3|6144 MB|NA|2.0 SAR
500076592,|2|4|7|10240 MB|NA|4.0 SAR
500076592,|5|1|1|4096 MB|NA|2.0 SAR
500076592,|5|2|3|6144 MB|NA|2.5 SAR
500076592,|5|4|7|10240 MB|NA|5.0 SAR
500076592,|1|1|1|100 MB|NA|0.5 SAR
500076592,|1|2|3|300 MB|NA|1.5 SAR
500076592,|1|4|7|1000 MB|NA|5.0 SAR
500076592,|11|1|1|100 MB|2 Minutes|1.0 SAR
500076592,|11|2|3|300 MB|5 Minutes|3.0 SAR
500076592,|6|1|1|NA|2 Minutes|0.5 SAR
500076592,|6|2|3|NA|5 Minutes|1.5 SAR
500076592,|6|4|7|NA|10 Minutes|3.0 SAR
500028952,|FINAL OFFER
500028952,|2|1|1|4096 MB|NA|1.5 SAR
500028952,|2|2|3|6144 MB|NA|2.0 SAR
500028952,|2|4|7|10240 MB|NA|4.0 SAR
500028952,|1|1|1|250 MB|NA|2.5 SAR
500028952,|1|2|3|650 MB|NA|6.5 SAR
500028952,|1|4|7|1550 MB|NA|15.5 SAR
500028952,|11|1|1|250 MB|2 Minutes|3.0 SAR
500028952,|11|2|3|650 MB|10 Minutes|8.0 SAR
500028952,|11|4|7|1550 MB|30 Minutes|18.5 SAR
500028952,|5|1|1|4096 MB|NA|2.0 SAR
500028952,|5|2|3|6144 MB|NA|2.5 SAR
500028952,|5|4|7|10240 MB|NA|5.0 SAR
500028952,|6|1|1|NA|2 Minutes|0.5 SAR
500028952,|6|2|3|NA|10 Minutes|1.5 SAR
500028952,|6|4|7|NA|30 Minutes|3.0 SAR
500028952,
```

Comment: Why do you have a line with just `500028952,` in the end of the second block? Should we also keep the `500076592,` line from the first one?

Comment: its of no need... i will remove this

Comment: If it isn't a problem, it is actually easier if we can keep it. Just make sure that the two blocks are consistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a pipe as a separator the data becomes easy to filter with `awk` based on the number of fields, e.g.:

```
awk -F'|' 'NF==2 { f=1 } NF==1 { f=0 } f' infile
```

Golfed:

```
awk -F\| 'NF==1{f=0}NF==2{f=1}f'
```

Comment: +1.  or `awk '/INITIAL OFFER/ {p=0};/FINAL OFFER/ {p=1};p'`

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -e '/FINAL OFFER/p;/INITIAL OFFER/,/FINAL OFFER/ d' input.csv  > output.csv
```

This prints the FINAL OFFER line again, because it's about to be deleted by the `/INITIAL OFFER/,/FINAL OFFER/` range.

Comment: note: if there happens to be a FINAL OFFER line without a preceding INITIAL OFFER, this will add a spurious FINAL OFFER line to the output.  If there are no other duplicate lines, you can fix this by piping to `uniq`.   If there are dupe lines that you need to keep, it becomes a more complicated job and awk or perl would be better suited than sed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sed` to delete everything between `INITIAL OFFER` and a line that has nothing but numbers and one comma:

```
$ sed '/INITIAL OFFER/,/^[0-9][0-9]*,$/d' file
500076592,|FINAL OFFER
500076592,|2|1|1|4096 MB|NA|1.5 SAR
500076592,|2|2|3|6144 MB|NA|2.0 SAR
500076592,|2|4|7|10240 MB|NA|4.0 SAR
500076592,|5|1|1|4096 MB|NA|2.0 SAR
500076592,|5|2|3|6144 MB|NA|2.5 SAR
500076592,|5|4|7|10240 MB|NA|5.0 SAR
500076592,|1|1|1|100 MB|NA|0.5 SAR
500076592,|1|2|3|300 MB|NA|1.5 SAR
500076592,|1|4|7|1000 MB|NA|5.0 SAR
500076592,|11|1|1|100 MB|2 Minutes|1.0 SAR
500076592,|11|2|3|300 MB|5 Minutes|3.0 SAR
500076592,|6|1|1|NA|2 Minutes|0.5 SAR
500076592,|6|2|3|NA|5 Minutes|1.5 SAR
500076592,|6|4|7|NA|10 Minutes|3.0 SAR
500076592,
500028952,|FINAL OFFER
500028952,|2|1|1|4096 MB|NA|1.5 SAR
500028952,|2|2|3|6144 MB|NA|2.0 SAR
500028952,|2|4|7|10240 MB|NA|4.0 SAR
500028952,|1|1|1|250 MB|NA|2.5 SAR
500028952,|1|2|3|650 MB|NA|6.5 SAR
500028952,|1|4|7|1550 MB|NA|15.5 SAR
500028952,|11|1|1|250 MB|2 Minutes|3.0 SAR
500028952,|11|2|3|650 MB|10 Minutes|8.0 SAR
500028952,|11|4|7|1550 MB|30 Minutes|18.5 SAR
500028952,|5|1|1|4096 MB|NA|2.0 SAR
500028952,|5|2|3|6144 MB|NA|2.5 SAR
500028952,|5|4|7|10240 MB|NA|5.0 SAR
500028952,|6|1|1|NA|2 Minutes|0.5 SAR
500028952,|6|2|3|NA|10 Minutes|1.5 SAR
500028952,|6|4|7|NA|30 Minutes|3.0 SAR
500028952,
```

If you don't want the `500076592,` and `500028952,` lines to be included, either use [@cas's simpler approach](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/648398/22222), or you can do this:

```
$ sed '/INITIAL OFFER/,/^[0-9][0-9]*,$/d; /^[0-9][0-9]*,$/d' file
500076592,|FINAL OFFER
500076592,|2|1|1|4096 MB|NA|1.5 SAR
500076592,|2|2|3|6144 MB|NA|2.0 SAR
500076592,|2|4|7|10240 MB|NA|4.0 SAR
500076592,|5|1|1|4096 MB|NA|2.0 SAR
500076592,|5|2|3|6144 MB|NA|2.5 SAR
500076592,|5|4|7|10240 MB|NA|5.0 SAR
500076592,|1|1|1|100 MB|NA|0.5 SAR
500076592,|1|2|3|300 MB|NA|1.5 SAR
500076592,|1|4|7|1000 MB|NA|5.0 SAR
500076592,|11|1|1|100 MB|2 Minutes|1.0 SAR
500076592,|11|2|3|300 MB|5 Minutes|3.0 SAR
500076592,|6|1|1|NA|2 Minutes|0.5 SAR
500076592,|6|2|3|NA|5 Minutes|1.5 SAR
500076592,|6|4|7|NA|10 Minutes|3.0 SAR
500028952,|FINAL OFFER
500028952,|2|1|1|4096 MB|NA|1.5 SAR
500028952,|2|2|3|6144 MB|NA|2.0 SAR
500028952,|2|4|7|10240 MB|NA|4.0 SAR
500028952,|1|1|1|250 MB|NA|2.5 SAR
500028952,|1|2|3|650 MB|NA|6.5 SAR
500028952,|1|4|7|1550 MB|NA|15.5 SAR
500028952,|11|1|1|250 MB|2 Minutes|3.0 SAR
500028952,|11|2|3|650 MB|10 Minutes|8.0 SAR
500028952,|11|4|7|1550 MB|30 Minutes|18.5 SAR
500028952,|5|1|1|4096 MB|NA|2.0 SAR
500028952,|5|2|3|6144 MB|NA|2.5 SAR
500028952,|5|4|7|10240 MB|NA|5.0 SAR
500028952,|6|1|1|NA|2 Minutes|0.5 SAR
500028952,|6|2|3|NA|10 Minutes|1.5 SAR
500028952,|6|4|7|NA|30 Minutes|3.0 SAR
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **GNU sed** with extended regex mode turned ON `-E`

```
sed -En '
  /^[^|]*\|?[^|]*$/h
  G;/\n.*\|/P
' file
```

Note:

- Stop  printing when you see a non pipe record.
- Start printing when you see a record with exactly one pipe.